# Django/React Dev Servers Choices

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm new to React. I'm building a project that uses Django to make a REST API and React to access the api. I have my backend running on http://localhost:8000/ & my frontend running on http://localhost:3000/. My frontend makes api requests to http://localhost:8000/api/v1/.

I found [this](http://v1k45.com/blog/modern-django-part-1-setting-up-django-and-react/) tutorial to get my frontend running on the index of http://localhost:8000/ for dev purposes. I would still have to have my React dev server and my Django dev server, but I also had to run 'npm run eject'.

Is there any advantage to either of these setups? I don't know too much about 'npm run eject' but since I can't go back from it, is it better off to wait on ejecting until I'm closer to deployment?

edit* - one advantage I see with the latter method, is I can set my permissions as so

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        #'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

instead of having to allow any. This would really only become an issue for deployment purposes too though.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I found on [documentation-link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md) for **npm run eject**

*this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!*

If you aren’t satisfied with the build tool and configuration choices, you can eject at any time. This command will remove the single build dependency from your project.
Instead, it will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. All of the commands except eject will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point you’re on your own.
You don’t have to ever use eject. The curated feature set is suitable for small and middle deployments, and you shouldn’t feel obligated to use this feature. However we understand that this tool wouldn’t be useful if you couldn’t customize it when you are ready for it.

It moves create-react-app’s configuration files and dev/build/test scripts into you app directory.
If you don’t have a need to modify the config or scripts you don’t need to eject. Doing so will prevent you from being able to update to new versions of create-react-app.
create-react-app gives you a fast and easy way to get up and running. It encapsulates the project setup and gives you tools to create production ready apps.
When you run npm eject it gives you access to all config files. This can be useful if you want to edit the webpack setup

so it has it's pros and cons choose what's best for you.

Comment: right It saw those, but at this moment in time I'm not sure of my personal pros and cons. Will I need to update create-react-app in the future is seemingly the biggest question I have to answer

Comment: Will I need to update create-react-app in the future? that's up to you to figure out how would someone tell you that you need to update or stick with legacy